# Detecting if device is used as laptop or tablet

Tags: c#

With many new devices such as the Vaio Duo, Vaio Flip, XPS 12, Lenovo Yoga, etc., which are all ultrabook/tablet convertibles, how can I detect which form factor its currently operating in?  I know that the Vaio Duo switches performance modes depending on whether its being used as a laptop or as a tablet, so there should be some way, whether it be through pinvoke or something else.

Comment: Why does this matter?

Answer (score 5):

In Windows, to directly check if your system is in tablet (or "slate") mode or not, you can call `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CONVERTIBLESLATEMODE)`. For a discussion of a sample app that does this, check out https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-write-a-2-in-1aware-application.

As well as checking on startup, you should be able to get a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message if the mode changes, which will have `"ConvertibleSlateMode"` as its `LPARAM`. In some cases, though, we've seen this message lost. So, it's a good idea to have a manual way to force a mode change in your app anyway.

Comment: Just note that this check is broken/ambiguous. If you use this on a non-convertible device it will always return '0' which is the same code that indicates that a device is in "slate/tablet" mode. I have not yet found a 100% reliable way to manage this. The best I can do so far is do some initial filtering via WMI on Win32_SystemEnclosure.ChassisTypes to see if the device looks like a convertible, then use this metrics check.

Comment: Do you know any example applications where I can test the mode awareness?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt your program work the same for all form factors, so there for it wouldnt matter which form factor there in.

Also have a look at this if you do need to access that sensor then this may help you.
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4906

This will get you all of your sensors.

```
Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Sensors.SensorManager.GetAllSensors();
```

Comment: Like the example I mentioned with the duo and its performance mode, it is similar.  For example, something like a music player may opt to show visualizations while running in laptop mode, but want to disable it for tablet mode to reduce cpu/gpu usage to keep temps down while you're holding it. Also, has this been discontinued? The last update seems to be from 2010.

Comment: Currently don't have access to a machine that I can test on. I'll let you know when I find out, probably sometime next week.

Comment: I added an answer that has more up to date information regarding this topic.  What I'm looking for seems to be associated with the inclinometer.

Comment: Maybe you just need to know whether or not a keyboard is connected/active?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on this  today. So I decided create a wrapper cause I haven't found one. I focused on universal portable class library (because of dispatcher used in monitor) but I can port to...

Here is:

https://github.com/daemun/DeviceExtCapabilitiesUniversal

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks very promising. I noticed that the NuGet package does not specify the license...

Answer (score 0):

Found a lot of information on this here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/ultrabook-and-tablet-windows-8-sensors-development-guide